# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decode'

Tags: python-3.x, pygal

```
names, plot_dicts = [], []
for repo_dict in repo_dicts:
    names.append(repo_dict['name'])
    plot_dict = {
        'value': repo_dict['stargazers_count'],
        'label': repo_dict['description'],
        'xlink': repo_dict['owner']['html_url'],
        }
    plot_dicts.append(plot_dict)

my_style = LS('#333366', base_style=LCS)
chart = pygal.Bar(style=my_style, x_label_rotation=45, show_legend=False)
chart.title = 'Most-Stared Python Project On Github'
chart.x_labels = names
chart.add('', plot_dicts)

chart.render_to_file('new_repos.svg')
```

*If I run this, there will be an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new_repos.py", line 54, in <module>
    chart.render_to_file('new_repos.svg')
  File "C:\Users\Cao Kangkang\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pygal\graph\public.py", line 114, in render_to_file
    f.write(self.render(is_unicode=True, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\Cao Kangkang\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pygal\graph\public.py", line 52, in render
    self.setup(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Cao Kangkang\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pygal\graph\base.py", line 217, in setup
    self._draw()
  File "C:\Users\Cao Kangkang\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pygal\graph\graph.py", line 933, in _draw
    self._plot()
  File "C:\Users\Cao Kangkang\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pygal\graph\bar.py", line 146, in _plot
    self.bar(serie)
  File "C:\Users\Cao Kangkang\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pygal\graph\bar.py", line 116, in bar 
    metadata)
  File "C:\Users\Cao Kangkang\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pygal\util.py", line 234, in decorate 
    metadata['label'])
  File "C:\Users\Cao Kangkang\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pygal\_compat.py", line 62, in to_unicode
    return string.decode('utf-8')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

*How ever if I change part of the code to this, the error will disappear, *however the description will be ignored in the chart.

```
names, plot_dicts = [], []
for repo_dict in repo_dicts:
    names.append(repo_dict['name'])
    plot_dict = {
        'value': repo_dict['stargazers_count'],
        #'label': repo_dict['description'],
        'xlink': repo_dict['owner']['html_url'],
        }
    plot_dicts.append(plot_dict)
```

*I don't know why, Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: error as text would be better BTW.

Answer (score 7):

```
'label':str(repo_dict['description'])
```

Try str() like above, it seems the data you got before hasn't clarifed the type of value that 'description' storged.

Answer (score 1):

May be the API didn't match the description, so you can use `ifelse` to solve it. Just like this.

```
description = repo_dict['description']
if not description:
    description = 'No description provided'

plot_dict = {
    'value': repo_dict['stargazers_count'],
    'label': description,
    'xlink': repo_dict['html_url'],
}
plot_dicts.append(plot_dict)`
```

If the web API returns the value `null`, it means there's no result, so you can solve it with if statement. Maybe here, the items `shadowsocks` didn't return anything, so it maybe something went wrong.

Comment: Code-Only answers are not considered as good answers. Please improve your answer by providing more context and explanations.

Answer (score 0):

```
from requests import get
from pygal import Bar, style, Config

url = "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:python&sort=stars"

# получение данных по API GitHub
get_data = get(url)
response_dict = get_data.json()
repositories = response_dict['items']

# получение данных для построения визуализации
names, stars_labels = [], []
for repository in repositories:
    names.append(repository['name'])
    if repository['description']:
        stars_labels.append({'value': repository['stargazers_count'],
                             'label': repository['description'],
                             'xlink': repository['html_url']})
    else:
        stars_labels.append({'value': repository['stargazers_count'],
                             'label': "нет описания",
                             'xlink': repository['html_url']})

# задание стилей для диаграммы
my_config = Config()
my_config.x_label_rotation = 45
my_config.show_legend = False
my_config.truncate_label = 15  # сокращение длинных названий проектов
my_config.show_y_guides = False  # скроем горизонтальные линии
my_config.width = 1300
my_style = style.LightenStyle('#333366', base_style=style.LightColorizedStyle)
my_style.label_font_size = 16
my_style.major_label_font_size = 20

# построение визуализации
chart = Bar(my_config, style=my_style)
chart.title = "Наиболее популярные проекты Python на GitHub"
chart.x_labels = names
chart.add('', stars_labels)
chart.render_to_file("python_projects_with_high_stars.svg")
```